# How to subscribe to a signal

Tags: python, nao-robot, pepper

I am trying to subscribe to a signal but I don't get it how exactly it is done.
I have read http://doc.aldebaran.com/2-4/dev/libqi/api/python/signal.html but still don't fully understand it. Here is a code where I am trying to wait for this signal `ALBehaviorManager.behaviorStopped('some_behavior')` and than invoke some callback:

```
service = session.service("ALBehaviorManager")

signal = qi.Signal(service.behaviorStopped('by_behavior'))

signal.connect(my_callback)
```

But get the following error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/testing.py", line 24, in <module>
    signal = qi.Signal(service.behaviorStopped('by_behavior'))
Boost.Python.ArgumentError: Python argument types in
    Signal.__init__(Signal, NoneType)
did not match C++ signature:
    __init__(struct _object *, class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >)
    __init__(struct _object *)
```

**EDITED**

```
service = session.service("ALBehaviorManager")

signal = qi.Signal()

signal(service.behaviorStopped('my_behavior'), my_callback())
```

When I run this it does not wait for the signal, it just call `my_callback`

**EDITED No.2**

```
import qi
import sys


def on_behavior_stopped_callback(behavior_id):
    if behavior_id == "test_video_player-fdb9c9/behavior_1":
        print "Yeah"
    else:
        print "Noooooo"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    ip = "11.1.11.111"
    port = 9559

    session = qi.Session()
    try:
        session.connect("tcp://" + ip + ":" + str(port))
    except RuntimeError:
        print ("Can't connect to Naoqi at ip \"" + ip + "\" on port " + str(port))
        sys.exit(1)

    behavior_manager_service = session.service("ALBehaviorManager")

    behavior_stopped_signal = behavior_manager_service.behaviorStopped

    behavior_stopped_connection = behavior_stopped_signal.connect(on_behavior_stopped_callback)
```

Based on your response (@JLS) when I run this python script it does nothing. Currently on the robot this `"test_video_player-fdb9c9/behavior_1"` is running. I thought the python script will not finish immediately but it would have waited for a signal from the type "behaviorStopped" to be received and when it has been received to check `if behavior_id == "test_video_player-fdb9c9/behavior_1"` and than do what it is supposed to do depending on the condition.

**EDITED No.3**

Lets have this situation: I have one behavior named 'listener' which only purpose is any time when other behavior is stopped to log the name of the stopped behavior. One way to do it is to make an event, that sends info to this 'listener'. Ok. everything works fine, but what to do when an build-in behavior stops such as 'dialog_runner_dev'. I thought if anytime a behavior stops it sends a signal that can be caught by this `ALBehaviorManager::behaviorStopped(std::string behaviorName)`.

My idea is to make a signal listener that works all the time. This signal listener to react when a behavior is stopped and then to continue listening for other behaviors.

Comment: Is your signal installed in the behavior 'my_behavior' ? if yes then it could make sense: your program has nothing to do after signal (that is non blocking) and so leave, and so just before your receive your callback (but you shouldn't as you're terminated...). Try adding a while 1 or a time.wait after the signal method to try to see changes... good luck...

Comment: @Alexandre Mazel That is the problem, the behavior is from the basic channel - 'run_dialog_dev'. It is responsible for running all the dialogs and it is going on and off depending on if the robot is talking with people or not. So I am trying to find a way to know when it is stopped. Perhaps and when it is starteed.

Comment: You can also use ALBehaviorManager to know when a behavior is launched and stopped: you can ask for list of running behaviors, and also register to some events tracking every time a behavior is installed/launched/started. cf API: http://doc.aldebaran.com/2-1/naoqi/core/albehaviormanager-api.html

Comment: @AlexandreMazel Please refer to EDDITED No.3

Comment: I'm not aware of a special case for built-in behavior, that's sad. If this is really this type of behavior, then perhaps as a workaround, you can ask directly to ALSpeechRecognition or ALDialog for their current state (or even aLAutonomousLife) ok, their are just workaround...

Answer (score 2):

Using qi.Signal() **creates** a signal. I guess here you want to **subscribe** to an existing signal, it will then call a callback function that you connect to it:

```
behavior_manager_service = session.service("ALBehaviorManager")
behavior_stopped_signal = behavior_manager_service.behaviorStopped
behavior_stopped_connection = behavior_stopped_signal.connect(on_behavior_stopped_callback)
```

with the callback function defined somewhere:

```
def on_behavior_stopped_callback(behavior_id):
    if behavior_id == "some_app_uuid/some_behavior":
        do_something()
```

and at the end:

```
behavior_stopped_signal.disconnect(behavior_stopped_connection)
```

**ADDENDUM:**

if you need to block and wait for the signal to happen, a trick is to use a thread-safe variable that your can wait for, like a promise, assigned from the callback. A [qi.Promise](http://doc.aldebaran.com/2-5/dev/libqi/api/python/future.html) can only be set once, so if you need it to happen several times, use a [Queue](https://docs.python.org/2/library/queue.html) instead.

1: define the variables somewhere where they will be accessible for you main and your callback:

```
pAnswer = qi.Promise()
fAnswer = pAnswer.future()
```

2: where you want the script to block, use

```
answer = fAnswer.value()
```

3: in the callback function, set the value:

```
pAnswer.setValue(ans)
```

Comment: Please refer to EDITED No.2

Comment: OK, I've added that answer as well! the subscription is only connecting a callback to a signal, not waiting for that signal to be raised. if you want to wait, you can use futures or other thread-safe systems like queues for example. Futures can only be set once.